# getline and while error in C++

Tags: c++

Hi I am a beginner for C++, and here is my practice code:

```
cout << "Hello World! "<< "Please enter your name" << " ";
//cin >> i;
getline(cin, mystring);
stringstream(mystring) >> name;
cout << "Please enter your password"<< " " ;
getline(cin, mystring);
stringstream(mystring) >> password;
cout << password << endl;

do {
    cout << "Sorry, your password does not match your name, please enter the password again" << " " << endl;
    getline(cin, mystring);
    stringstream(mystring) >> password;
} while (!(name == "victor" & password == "victor"));
```

I wonder why the result is as follows that "Sorry..." appears even the password is correct?

> Hello World! Please enter your name `victor`
>
> Please enter your password `victor`
>
> victor
>
> Sorry, your password does not match your name, please
> enter the password again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `do...while` loop always executes at least once because the test at the bottom is performed at the end of the loop.

So you will always see the message about the wrong password at least once. If you want to execute the loop only when the condition is true, use a regular `while` loop with the condition at the top.

Also, the logic *AND* operator is `&&` and not `&`.

```
while (!(name == "victor" && password == "victor"));
{
    cout << "Sorry, your password does not match your name, please enter the password again" << " " << endl;
    getline(cin, mystring);
    stringstream(mystring) >> password;
}
```

Comment: You should also replace the while with !(name == password). This way it can work with any name

Comment: @Mitchel0022, thx for your suggestion. But what I want here is to have a password-name list so that I could let people I know to log in the system. But still, thx !